# Run sql query on column from excel

Tags: sql, excel

I've been running a lot of queries by copy and pasting a column from one table in excel or from a table in another db. The only problem with this, is the commas need to be added and so do the quotation marks if it is a varchar field.

If I want to copy and paste a column to run a query on, what is an easy way to get it in the correct format?

ex:

```
 select * from table1 where columnName in ('row one',
'row two',
'row three',
'row four',
'row five')
```

Comment: Which database? Does Googling for "[database name] CSV" help at all?

Comment: You can save your excel or just the column you want in .csv format, then you can add the quotes with any editor (e.g notepad++)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to quickly generate SQL statements from Excel data, I can suggest this:

Write the following formula in an empty cell:

```
="insert into table values('" &B3 &"','" & C3 & "','"&D3&"');"
```

where B3, C3, D3 refer to table data.

The new cell will the SQL string with correct values.

Source: http://chandoo.org/wp/2008/09/22/sql-insert-update-statements-from-csv-files/

Answer (score 0):

I have created a User Defined Function to build comma seperated lists. I have in in a .xla file so that is is always available to me.

Basically, it allows me to select a single column of data, and create a list with any seperator I choose (comma as the default) and allows me to specify if quotation marks should be used (turn these off for numeric values).

```
Function CommaList(DataRange As Range, Optional Seperator As String = ",", Optional Quotes As Boolean = True) As String
    Dim iCellNum As Integer
    Dim sTemp As String

    If DataRange.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        CommaList = "Select a Single Column"
        Exit Function
    End If

    For iCellNum = 1 To DataRange.Cells.Count
        If Quotes Then
            sTemp = sTemp + "'" + DataRange.Cells(iCellNum, 1) + "'"
        Else
            sTemp = sTemp + DataRange.Cells(iCellNum, 1)
        End If
        If iCellNum < DataRange.Cells.Count Then
            sTemp = sTemp + Seperator
        End If
    Next iCellNum

    CommaList = sTemp

End Function
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to SQL. How do I use this function and where do I place it?

Comment: This is not SQL. It is a vba function that you would run in excel.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion involves using the Replace() function to convert all the tabs (Char(9)) to ',' then to change all the 'line feeds' (CHar(13)) into ','. Your result is then 'Commafied and quoted'

```
Declare @String Varchar(max)

set @string = 
'row one
row two
row three
row four'

set @string = '''' + replace ( replace(@string, Char(9) ,''' , ''' ),Char(13) ,''' , ''' )+ ''''
print @string
```

this makes the result 'look' prettier:

```
set @string = replace (replace ( replace(@string, Char(9) ,''' , ''' ),Char(13) ,''' , ''' ), Char(10), '')
print @string
```

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar, also using the "in" clause.

If you copying from excel, format your data in another column first using the concatenate function. 
So to add a comma to cell A2 for eg, `=Concatenate(A2,",")`. copy this down all rows. then copy and paste the colum in sql etc.